# Why does this EA (in early development) not produce an alert, or an error?

Tags: mql4

```
#property strict

string subfolder = "ipc\\";
int last_read = 0;
int t = 0;
struct trade_message 
  { 
   int   time;       // time 
   string   asset;      // asset 
   string   direction;  // direction
   double   open_price; // open
   double   stop_price; // open
   double   close_price;// open
   float    fraction;   // fraction
   string   comment;    // comment
   string   status;     // status
  };
trade_message messages[];

int OnInit()
  {
  int FH = FileOpen(subfolder+"processedtime.log",FILE_BIN);
  if(FH >=0)
   {
   last_read = FileReadInteger(FH,4);
   FileClose(FH);
   } 
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }

void OnTick()
  {
  int FH=FileOpen(subfolder+"data.csv",FILE_READ|FILE_CSV, ","); //open file
  int p=0;
  while(!FileIsEnding(FH))
  {
  t = StringToInteger(FileReadString(FH));
  if(t<=last_read)
   {
   break;
   }
  do
   {
   messages[p].time = t;                                          // time
   messages[p].direction = FileReadString(FH);                    // direction
   messages[p].open_price = StringToDouble(FileReadString(FH));   // open
   messages[p].stop_price = StringToDouble(FileReadString(FH));   // stop
   messages[p].close_price = StringToDouble(FileReadString(FH));  // close
   messages[p].fraction = StringToDouble(FileReadString(FH));     // fraction (?float)
   messages[p].comment = FileReadString(FH);                      // comment
   messages[p].status = FileReadString(FH);                       // status
   Alert(messages[p].comment);
   }
   while(!FileIsLineEnding(FH));
   p++;
   Alert("P = ",p,"; Array length = ", ArraySize(messages));

   }

  FileClose(FH);
  last_read = t;
  FileDelete(subfolder+"processedtime.log");
  FH = FileOpen(subfolder+"processedtime.log",FILE_BIN);
  FileWriteInteger(FH,t,4);
  FileClose(FH);
  ArrayFree(messages);
  }
```

The code is in tick function in order to test it before taking it out to a function.
The `data.csv` file is:

| Timestamp | Asset | Direction | Price | Stop | Profit | Fraction | Comment | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | SHORT | 13240 | 13240 | 13220 | 0.5 | yyy SHORT 13240 - taken half at 13220 and stop to breakeven | U |
| xxx | yyy | SHORT | 13240 | 13262 | 13040 | 1.0 | 55% | DP |

The `processedtime.log` is not being created.

Comment: It doesn't work as a script either...

Comment: In which location did you expect the file to get created? Kindly post an absolute `(volume):\(fully_qualified_file_path)` thanks

Comment: if you know the mql sandbox you will know that ```"ipc\\";``` defines a path relative to the data folder for the instance of the terminal in which the EA or Script is being run. However, just to be clear, substituting ```string subfolder = "C:\\Users\\andyt\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\2C68BEE3A904BDCEE3EEF5A5A77EC162\\MQL4\\Files\\ipc\\";``` for ```string subfolder = "ipc\\";``` leads to FH = -1, as I expected, while leaving the shorter assignment leads to a successful (FH > 0) result for the ```FileOpen()``` statements

Comment: Duh - forgot to skip header row - I will rewrite the source script that produces the csv and omit it. I'll update when tested...

Answer (score 0):

So 2 problems, both of my own making.

1. Not skipping the header row, simply remedied by inserting

```
do f = FileReadString(FH);
while(!FileIsLineEnding(FH));
```

after FileOpen() (easier than altering my source for `data.csv`), and

2. forgetting about the asset part of my structure, thus ensuring my structures got out of sync with my lines!! Remedied by adding `messages[p].asset = FileReadString(FH);` between `messages[p].time = t` and `messages[p].direction = FileReadString(FH);`